# mvnw clean install throwing the following errors

Tags: java, maven, neovim

I am trying to set up nvim for java development, I am rather new to all this, and hence am following this tutorial, because it didn't work when I tried on my own.
[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q_MKUynUck)

I first cloned this [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/java-debug) using ssh, then i did a mvnw clean install as told.

and i got the following errors

```
1 error @
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 2 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.microsoft.java:com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin:0.41.0 (/home/demo/.config/nvim/java-debug/com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid artifact repository: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.p2.P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout not present
[ERROR]       at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:2.7.3, parent: java.net.URLClassLoader@2cb4c3ab] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR]       at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:2.7.3, parent: java.net.URLClassLoader@2cb4c3ab] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR]       while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=p2)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     1 error: org/eclipse/tycho/core/p2/P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.microsoft.java:com.microsoft.java.debug.repository:0.41.0 (/home/demo/.config/nvim/java-debug/com.microsoft.java.debug.repository/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid artifact repository: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.p2.P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout not present
[ERROR]       at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:2.7.3, parent: java.net.URLClassLoader@2cb4c3ab] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR]       at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:2.7.3, parent: java.net.URLClassLoader@2cb4c3ab] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR]       while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=p2)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     1 error: org/eclipse/tycho/core/p2/P2ArtifactRepositoryLayout has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Is there any chance that this could be a firewall error? Because I am on a public network currently

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to build that project using Java 8 (class file 52.0) and some of its dependencies requires Java 11 (class file version 55.0).

See:

- https://www.java.com/releases/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout